# React native DatePickerAndroid Calendar customization

Tags: react-native

On Default React native DatePickerAndroid gives a calendar starting with Sunday.How to customize that Calendar to start with Monday

Answer (score 0):

The DatePickerAndroid uses the underlying DatePicker in Android SDK:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker

It has an option - firstDayOfWeek.

```
DatePickerAndroid.open({
 firstDayOfWeek: 2
});
```

Comment: Add a feature request in React native to support this. And if possible do a PR.

Comment: what do you mean by PR?